# Validate PrivateKey against Root CA PublicKey

Tags: java, x509, ca

I need to validate privateKey (pk8) against Root CA publicKey (from certificate) using java, is it possible?
if it isn't possible, how can I get X509Certificate from RSAPrivateKey?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You don't have the root CA's private key, you have your own private key. You can't get a private key from a certificate, or *vice versa.* You can validate *your* certificate, with *your* public key, but validating a private key against somebody else's public key is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal to know if your private key matches the public key, you can encrypt something using your private key and decrypt using public key. If you able to do it, then it matches.

Try using the [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) API.

Here's a sample [code](https://github.com/Exakt/johne.repo/blob/tv5/TV5Web/src/ph/com/exakt/auth/AuthProcessor.java)

hopes it helps :)

Comment: Johne, thank you for answer! could you provide example plz? thanks